# How to extract 20-80 relations from data (Pareto principle)?

Tags: pareto-distribution

There are certain input-output processes that display a "[20-80 relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle)". That is, given Y depending on X, there are subsets of X consisting 20% of the input set that generate 80% of the output.  For example, 20% of clients may generate 80% of revenues (or complaints), 20% of product flaws generate 80% of complaints, etc.

Are there known methods to see if a given data set satisfies this 20-80 principle?